# Android image file size limit and how to handle large images?

Tags: android, image

If we work with large images (bitmaps) we will hit a wall eventually in the size the image is allowed to be (in order to be displayed). I wondered if anyone knows where this limit is? There is many factors in this, the maximum heap size of the phone etc.

Also is there any workaround to handling large images if you want to display them and make them interact-able?

Comment: Did you find this out?

Comment: @Lijo there is a lot of libraries that support this feature as far as I remember. Just search for zoomeable images. Also Android supports svg/vector images now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have decoded image data,  you can store them in  file on storage
and then mmap this buffer.

Then you can create sub-images (tiles) over this buffer via [createBitmap function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29)

MMapped memory areas do not count agains heap,  are not subject for garbage collection 
and are handled by paging subsystem bypassing usual file operations.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage or send me in a direction to read more about it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html - makes  your file magically appear as byte buffer

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't marked this as the correct answer but since I haven't been able to do a test on it I have nothing but your word that this would work. I might try it in the future :)

Comment: @Warpzit have u tried this solution? Can anyone provide an example? it is very disappointing and weird that Android doesn't provide a builtin solution for handling zoomable Large images. Android should provide an image view which handles large images using caching / tiles. I have searched alot and couldn't find a single appropriate library for this. sigh..

Answer (score 2):

To compress large image size you can use

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display whole image fullscreen then delegate it to build-in application:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
startActivity(i);
```

When you want to display it as a thumbnail etc then read [this doc](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

This article talks about working with large bitmaps and dealing with memory constraints. It also talks about a few factors that cause the OutOfMemoryErrors such as heap size, other bitmaps loaded into memory and memory fragmentation. Finally, it provides an algorithm to dynamically load the largest possible image file into memory and perform transforms.

http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/handling-large-images-on-android/

Comment: Yes but this is basically just reducing quality. Most of the time that isn't a solution :)