# Saving large image to PNG

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I've just encontered a tough problem...

Here's my story:

My device is Samsung Galaxy Note, normally, it takes pictures at a resolution of **3264 * 2448** pixels. I love fine pictures when am tring to find detailed information, but here I hate it because it's huge to handle in Android. I can read and display an image of this big resolution, I need to draw lines on top of it, then I need to save both picture and lines to a png.
My headache is that my Android always gives me **Out of memery exception**, when am trying to create a mutable bitmap like this:

```
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(3264, 2448, Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas cv = new Canvas(bmp);
    //draw a line and save and restore canvas
    // I found an alternative solution yet proven to be uncorrect:
    myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    myImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bmp = myImageView.getDrawingCache();
    //save bmp to png
```

When the

```
bmp.width * bmp.height * 4 > getScaledMaximumDrawingCacheSize()
```

exception jumps out. I've tested `myImageView.measure(...)` and `myImageView.layout(...)`, didn't work for me.
(Things are fine, when I test the same code using smaller images)

Any experts know how to kill this problem or throw a solution to me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you calculated the memory required to hold a bitmap of that size and quality. It's huge regardless of the platform you are developing for, but as you have found more troublesome on restricted memory devices if you are not carefully managing your bitmap objects.

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993568/android-image-file-size-limit-and-how-to-handle-large-images

Comment: You might want to try first chunk the big bitmap into several pieces then carefully draw & align the lines on them. Then you need to put the small pieces back to the complete large bitmap.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but how does it work? I mean have u got any source code or sth detailed? I have difficulty in doing this...

Comment: Simply resize image to fit with current display. I done that with my surfaceView to draw image from gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the definitve solution, but did you try to increase heap size?

For Android 2.2 or lower versions:

```
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(sizeInBytes);
```

For Android [2.3 or or higher versions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap):

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```